# Не срабатывает якорь в tabpanel bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Здравствуйте.
Стоит задача такова, при нажатии кнопки которая является элементом навигации tabpanel срабатывала плавная прокрутка к якорю, каким образом это осуществить? Пример кода здесь https://jsfiddle.net/04Lhqshu/1/

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <!-- Навигация -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Домой</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Профиль</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Сообщения</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Настройки</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Содержимое вкладок -->

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текстаОчень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текстаОчень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текстаОчень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текстаОчень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текстаОчень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Очень много текста </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Очень много текста </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">.Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста </div>
  </div>
   <a name="home"> </a>
  <div> к примеру, тут якорь</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Кто-то сможет помочь?

Comment: Кто-то сможет помочь? Плз)

Comment: Кто-то может помочь?

Comment: Кто-то сможет помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У вас класс актив прописан к `li`, а нужно его прописывать к ссылке.
2. У вас в примере не добавлен `jquery`, для скриптов бутстрапа его нужно подключать.
3. В скриптах бутсрапа нет плавной прокрутки, напишите ее сами. Плавная прокрутка так же осуществляется к `id` не по `name`. Например можете сделать по классу ссылки, например:

```js
$(function() {
  $("a.to-ancor").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show')
    var _href = $(this).attr("href");
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(_href).offset().top + "px"
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <!-- Навигация -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li><a class="active to-ancor" href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Домой</a></li>
    <li><a class="to-ancor" href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Профиль</a></li>
    <li><a class="to-ancor" href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Сообщения</a></li>
    <li><a class="to-ancor" href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Настройки</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Содержимое вкладок -->

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">1. Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста
      Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста
      Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текстаОчень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста
      Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста
      Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текстаОчень много текста
      Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста
      Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста
      Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текстаОчень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста
      Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текстаОчень много текста
      Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста
      Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста
      Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текстаОчень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста
      Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста
      Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста
      Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">2. Очень много текста </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">3. Очень много текста </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">4. Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Kizoso, Спасибо большое, действует практически также, как мне нужно, но проблема, табы перестали работать! даже в Вашем примере не работают. :(

Comment: @Pubat извиняюсь, исправила.

Comment: благодарю за помощь!